$R_x(\theta)$ and $R_y(\theta)$ implement rotations by an angle $\theta$ about the x and y axes of the Bloch sphere
Consider the operators (to be called rotations) :
$$R_x(\theta)= \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta/2) & -i\sin(\theta/2)\\
-i\sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2)\end{pmatrix}= e^{-iX\theta/2} \\ 
R_y(\theta)= \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\theta/2) & -\sin(\theta/2)\\
\sin(\theta/2) & \cos(\theta/2)\end{pmatrix} = e^{-iY\theta/2}$$
Show that they implement rotations through an angle $\theta$ about the x and y axes of the Bloch sphere.
Recall that a state on the Bloch sphere can be written $$\cos(\alpha/2)\ |0\rangle+ e^{i\beta}\sin(\alpha/2)\ |1\rangle$$ and is represented by the point $(\alpha, \beta)$ on the sphere, or in Cartesian coordinates $(\sin \alpha \cos \beta, \sin \alpha \sin \beta, \cos \alpha)$.

It looks like a homework exercise. What did you try so far?

Using this formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula
But I am looking for another (possibly shorter) answer.
